# BeginForm Always calling Index when submitting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC BeginForm to submit form data to my ActionMethod in Controller. The problem is that when every I click on submit button it keeps calling Index method instead of Actual method defined in BeginForm.

Here is my View

```
   @model HRMS.DBModel.department
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("save", "Department", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

and here is the Department Controller

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
    // GET: Department
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult save()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Location", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I searched on google even found solutions but still my problem is still there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved there was a form tag inside my Master page due to which it was calling Index Method, I removed that form tag and now its working fine